# CDI Event and XA transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, xa

I'm using Java EE 6.
I'd like to trigger an action upon successful commit of a transaction. For now, my plan is to use a CDI transactional event within an EJB:

```
@Asynchronous
public void triggerAction(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) MyEvent myEvent){
    // Do something with the event
}
```

The transaction triggering the event can be involved in a XA distributed transaction.

**At which phase of the two phase commit will the observer be called ?**

The documentation states:

> An after success observer method is called during the after completion phase of the transaction, only when the transaction completes successfully.

I'm not sure what this implies when using distributed transactions.

Further, is there any warranty that the data is already in DB (i.e. can my observer method be called when the decision to commit is reached, but the data are not yet persisted in DB ?).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CDI 1.x does not define the behavior of events in async call stacks.  The behavior you will see will be container specific, including some containers that invoke this method synchronously instead of async.  CDI 2.0 is introducing an async observer for events.

Answer (score 0):

the XA transaction manager is responsible for 'applying' XA semantics, meaning it has to go through the 2 Phase Commit (dialog) with all the involved parties (distributed parties) and then it will commit and consider (if no errors) it as done.

In you case, the observer will be called when the data in the db will be commited in the context of the transaction and not in any previous or interim state.